# Why do I obtain always error with ajax into my php web page?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want delete a record from database and to do it I want use ajax..

So I have a table where I put into last `td` this:

```
<input type='image' src='./img/delete.png' onClick='deleteUser(".$utentiIscritti[$i][0].");' />
```

this is my `deleteUser` function:

```
function deleteUser(id){
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type:"post",
                                        url: "deleteUserAjax.php",
                                        data: {'id':id},
                                        success: function(data){
                                            console.log("OK");
                                            location.reload();
                                        },
                                       error: function(xhr, status, error){
                                           alert(xhr+"\n\n"+status+"\n\n"+error);
                                           console.log("KO");
                                       }
                                    });
                                }
```

And this is my php page to connect to db and delelte the record:

```
<?php
$USERDB = "u";
$PASSWORDDB = "p";
$NAMEDB = "d";

$queryDeleteUser = 'delete from user where id = "'.$_POST['id'].'"';
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", $USERDB, $PASSWORDDB)
        or die("Errore nella connessione al database: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($NAMEDB) or die("Errore nella selezione del database: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query($queryDeleteUser) or die("Errore nella query: " . $queryDeleteUser . "\n" . mysql_error());
dbDisconnect($conn);
```

But I obtain always (from every ajax request) error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
iscritti.php:80
```

Why???

Comment: Have you tried to run the script without ajax?

Comment: @AdRock I don't understand what you want tell me... If i remove ajax there is nothing into my script...

Comment: @BrianCoolidge can you spify where??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider two solutions.

1. Your code is buggy. Try to execute it on it's own. Just call it in your browser and check the result!
2. You have specified a relational path for your script. `url: "deleteUserAjax.php"`, try instead an absolute path and check the result (`url: "http://yourdomain.com/deleteUserAjax.php"`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make it more cleaner:

HTML part:

```
<input type='image' src='./img/delete.png' value='<?=$id?>'>
```

jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete").on("click", function(){
        var data = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "page_you_handle_it.php?action=delete",
            data: {'id':id}
        }).done(function(data){
            //here you get response of your delete function!
        });
    });
});
```

PHP part:

```
$host = "[HOST]"; //Like localhost
$user = "[USER]"; //Like root
$pass = "[PASS]"; //Like 123
$db = "[DB]"; //Like users

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Conntecting the Database gone wrong");

$id = $_POST['id'];

$query_str = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query_str);

if (!$query) //Do not run the `$query` in the return parts because it already runs when you say `if (!$query)`
{
    echo 'Delete gone wrong';
}
else
{
    echo 'Delete succes!';
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I would have used PDO tho